# Extjs TwoWayBindable pressed button

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I want to create a button which is property "pressed" is binded to a data in a view model.
But it didn't work, I don't understand why.

See my fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16i2.
My problem is that the `extended` property value doesn't change.

I know that I can do this by event, but I want to understand why it doesn't work and how to this with ExtJs property before going to a "workaround".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `reference` solves the issue.

For example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16ir

Comment: @Psycho I have no idea why. (But you must get used to strange behaviors with Sencha's products :-))